# Pra quê serve o metodo __new__ in python?

Tags: python

```
class Fabrica(object):
    """ pra quê serve o metodo __new__ in python? """

    def __new__(cls[, ...]):
        # seu codigo aqui

#EOF
```

O que *ela* faz, e como fazer o uso dele?

Comment: Há uma pergutna relacionada recente, cuja resposta também é interessante aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109813/onde-fica-o-construtor-da-classe-em-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo a definição abaixo:

> Use o ***__new__*** quando você precisar controlar a criação de uma nova
>   instancia da classe. Use o ***__init__*** quando você precisar controlar
>   a inicialização de uma nova instancia.
>
> O ***__new__*** é o primeiro passo da criação de uma instancia. Ele é
>   chamado primeiro, e é responsavel por retornar uma nova instancia da
>   sua classe. Em contraste, o ***__init__*** não retorna nada, ele é apenas
>   responsável pela inicialização da instancia após a classe ser
>   criada.
>
> Em geral, você não deveria sobrepor o ***__new__*** ao menos que seja
>   uma subclasse, um tipo imutável como `str`, `int`, `unicode` ou
>   `tuple`.

Ou seja, voce pode usar o `__new__` para ter um controle da criação da instancia da classe e apos ele usar o `__init__` para passar argumentos, veja um exemplo:

```
class Fabrica(object):
    """ pra quê serve o metodo __new__ in python? """

    def __new__(cls[, ...]):
        # seu código aqui
        # definir uma rotina no momento da criação da instancia.
    def __init__(self, nome):
        # aqui ocorre a inicialização da instancia, 
        # pode iniciar os atributos da classe aqui.
        self.nome = nome
```

O `__new__` pode ser usado com tipos de classes imutáveis como `float`, `str` ou `int` tem um exemplo que tirei do artigo *Unificando Tipos Classes*, um programa que converte polegadas para metro:

```
class inch(float):
    "Converte de polegadas para metros"
    def __new__(cls, arg=0.0):
        return (float.__new__(cls, arg*0.0254))

print(inch(12))
```

Saída: `0.3048`

Mas, este uso eu achei muito interessante no artigo, realmente pode vir a ser útil se você for utilizar o padrão [singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), segue o exemplo:

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        it = cls.__dict__.get("__it__")
        if it is not None:
            return it
        cls.__it__ = it = object.__new__(cls)
        it.init(*args, **kwds)
        return it
    def init(self, *args, **kwds):
        pass
```

Fontes:
[Documentação.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)
[Python's use of `__new__` and `__init__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/5429980)
[UnificandoTiposClasses](http://wiki.python.org.br/UnificandoTiposClasses) , aconselho muito a leitura se quiser saber mais a respeito.