# Onde fica o construtor da classe em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor

Definição da Wikipédia.

> O [construtor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construtor) é um método
>   que geralmente é responsável pela alocação de recursos necessários ao
>   funcionamento do objeto além da definição inicial das variáveis de
>   estado (atributos).

Em Python normalmente é usado o método `__init__` para definir os valores dos atributos, isto é o que eu compreendo a respeito deste método, ou seja, em meu ponto de vista ele é um construtor. Veja o exemplo para a ilustração:

```
class Carro(object):
    def __init__(self, modelo, ano): #Construtor da classe.
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.ano = ano

meuCarro = Carro("Jeep 4x4", 2015)

print("Modelo: %s" % meuCarro.modelo)
print("Ano: %d" % meuCarro.ano)
```

Contudo, na [pesquisa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6579300/5429980) que fiz, eu descobri que o método `__init__` não é o *construtor* da classe, e sim o método chamado quando um objeto é requerido. Agora fiquei confuso a respeito de onde é o local de um *construtor* de uma classe em Python. Onde seria o local do *construtor*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## O que é um construtor

Isso é uma tecnicalidade e podemos considerá-lo como o construtor. De fato ele é um inicializador, conforme já havia escrito em [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109013/101), mas o inicializador será chamado todas as vezes que for criado um objeto novo, logo após chamar o `__new__` que será o alocador de memória do objeto. Este alocador é provido pela linguagem se você não definir um, o que raramente é necessário, normalmente em objetos imutáveis pode ser interessante.

E é isso, se fizer uma pesquisa mais profunda verá que todos, no dia a dia, chamarão o `__init__` de construtor. Se não chamar ele de construtor então todas linguagens que eu conheço estão usando o nome errado, porque o que elas chamam de construtor também é um inicializador. Elas também costumam chamar o alocador implicitamente e normalmente não é necessário defini-lo em todas as classes. Claro que se for ser detalhista a terminologia não é bem essa mesmo.

`__del__` é o destrutor, certo? Ou é só um "desinicializador", ou só um desalocador? Para todos os efeitos, ele destrói o objeto. Ele é o oposto do `__new__` ou o oposto do `__init__`? A documentação diz que ele é um destrutor. Então um dos dois é o construtor :).

A construção do objeto em Python ocorre em dois passos, o que também é verdade em várias linguagens. Nem sempre é aparente porque a alocação costuma ser pouco explorada. Em C++, por exemplo, é possível sobrepor o operador `new` para criar uma alocação personalizada. Em C# ou Java não é possível. Mas note que nessas linguagens o construtor é só um inicializador, e por acaso sempre será chamado o alocador, que é fixo, antes de inicializar os membros, mas a construção é a inicialização. Então podemos dizer que o inicializador é o construtor. E claro que ele nunca poderá ser chamado antes de chamar o alocador.

## Constructor expression

O que você pode fazer é criar uma expressão de construtor, que é uma forma de dar ao consumidor daquela classe um jeito de explicitamente fazer toda construção do objeto e, obviamente deverá fazer a alocação e a inicialização de alguma forma, mesmo que chamando os método que já sabem fazer isto, o que não faria sentido se for para fazer exatamente a mesma coisa. E é claro que precisa saber o que está fazendo para não cometer erros. Ele é uma forma de dar mais flexibilidade para a construção.

Para criar uma forma da classe fazer outras atividades além da alocação e inicialização, precisa dar capacidade dela ser [chamada como uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109102/101). Isto se dá criando um método `__call__`. Então:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
    def __call__(self):
        print("call ")

a = A() #imprime init
a() #imprime call
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/InitClass.py).

Se ambos tiverem a mesma assinatura, o `__init__` será chamado, a não ser que chame o `__call` explicitamente, simplificadamente: `A()()`. O `__init__` sempre será chamado antes.

[Exemplos de uso do `__call__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5824881/221800).

Eu não chamaria isso de construtor.

## Factory method

Ainda é possível criar um método estático (sem o `self`) que pode ser chamado para invocar a construção do objeto, mas não vejo isto com bons olhos. Não me parece idiomático.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VBpPSZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lqdolocr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/Constructor.py).

## Leitura adicional

A [documentação sobre objetos do Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html) é uma boa leitura para entender tudo isto. Um [artigo que fala bastante sobre estes métodos mágicos](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html).

Comment: Reparei agora que na última linha do exemplo deveria ser `a() #imprime call`, pois `__call__` é chamado ao invocar a instância, não a classe. Provavelmente um erro digitação, mas pode confundir o leitor.

Comment: @fernandosavio sim, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

o Método `__init__` é o inicializador da classe, tanto que o momento que ele é executado você já possui a instância criada (`self`), em python o método construtor de classe é o `__new__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls):
        return cls()
```

Repare que diferente do `__init__` o método `__new__` precisa retornar um valor, no caso a instancia da classe que está sendo criada. Veja a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) para mais detalhes.

Um exemplo de uso do método `__new__` é na criação de objetos *singletons*:

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

Porem, em 99% dos casos, você não precisa (e talvez não deva) alterar o método construtor da sua classe.

Comment: Não esqueça de que classes que não herdam de "object" devem ser usadas apenas em Python3. Fazer isso em Python2 cria classes "old-style" que são incompatíveis com muitas das coisas que foram acrescentadas ao Python nos últimos 15 anos (sim, old-style é OLD) - e pior, fica bem díficil de achar o erro.

Comment: Não esqueci, mas para mim está claro que quem fez a pergunta está usando python3 pelo print como função (e quero crer que ele não omitiu nenhum import, como por exemplo `from __future__ import print_function`)

Comment: Mas tem que deixar claro para as outras pessoas que chegarem aqui. A pergunta não está tagueada como Python3. (bom, isso podemos corrigir)