# Qual é a diferença entre __init__ e __new__?

Tags: python, classes, característica-linguagem, métodos-mágicos

Qual é a diferença entre os métodos especiais `__init__` e `__new__` em Python?

Comment: Por gentileza, poderia informar o motivo do negativo? (sem esperança de respostas)

Comment: Tenho minhas suspeitas, mas esse `textarea` não conteria minhas palavras. Obs: não phui eu.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109013/101

Comment: Possível duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109784/101

Comment: Juntando as duas acho que é duplicata

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pra quê serve o metodo \_\_new\_\_ in python?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109784/pra-qu%c3%aa-serve-o-metodo-new-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O `__new__` é chamado pelo Python *antes* do objeto ser efetivamente construído: isso é, ter memória alocada para ele, ponteiros inicializados, e possivelment mais algumas coisas - todas essas coisas são feitas no código nativo, em C, dentro do método `__new__` da classe fundamental `object`.

Quando você faz um override de `__new__`, em algum ponto você vai ter que (em código normal)  chamar o `__new__` da superclasse - e isso se repete até que a classe mais alta na hierarquia chame o `__new__` de `object` - esse `__new__` devolve a instância do objeto - isso é, o objeto que é passado como `self`  para todos os métodos de instância. O seu método `__new__` tem que retornar esse `self`.

É possível ter um método  `__new__` que retorne outra coisa - mas nesse caso, é impossível se ter uma instância propriamente dita da classe que tem esse método `__new__`: o mecanismo de classes do Python é usado para alguma outra coisa.  Por exemplo, o mecanismo de `interfaces`  do Zope (pacote `zope.interface`) não cria objetos propriamente ditos, e apenas usa a sintaxe de classe quando voce herda de `zope.interface.Interface`.

Depois de chamar o `__new__`, o método `__init__` é chamado. Ele é chamado tecnicamente de "inicializador", e já recebe a instância do objeto no primeiro parâmetro - "self", em geral - com tod a a parte de alocaçã de memória feita - o `__init__`então pode fazer toda  a inicialização de atributos e recursos feita no nível do Python.

Em quase todos os casos só precisamos escrever o método `__init__` - é bem raro precisar mexer no `__new__`.  E de qualquer forma, se não existisse o `__init__`, tudo que é feito nele poderia ser feito dentro do `__new__` dessa forma:

```
class SemInit(object):
     def __new__(cls, param1, param2, **kwargs):
          self = super().__new__(cls)
          # código que iria no __init__ vai aqui:
          ...
          return self
```

Então, em suma, o passo a passo da instanciação de um objeto é o seguinte:

quando se faz `a = MinhaClasse()`, o método `__call__` da objeto `MinhaClasse`- em si (isso, em Python classes são elas mesmas objetos e via de regra são  instâncias da classe especial `type` (ela é chamada de "metaclasse"). então, esse método `__call__` da classe `type` é chamado - ele está escrito em C, mas o pseudo código para ele, se fosse em Python seria:

```
class type:
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         self = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
         result = cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         if result is not None:
              raise TypeError("TypeError: __init__() should return None, not '{}'".format(result))
         return self
```

E sim, em Python é válido o recurso de "metaclasses" que consiste em fazer uma subclasse de type e modificar o mecanismo de criação de classes e instâncias acima - então escrevendo um método `__call__` como o acima, desde que ele chame  o `object.__new__` passando a classe como parâmetrpo  em algum ponto, você pode criar classes que não usam o `__init__`, ou que tem mais de um tipo de `__init__`, etc...

EU disse que todo mundo tem que chamar o `__new__` do `object` do Python : em, com código em Python puro é a única forma de se criar um objeto.

É possível, no entanto, criar-se código usando uma extensão em C, ou mesmo alocando-se estruturas de dados "na mão" com o módulo "ctypes"  que crie um objeto de forma diferente.

**atualização**: E quando devemos codificar o `__new__`?

Quando  vamos criar uma subclasse de um tipo de dado nativo "imutável" do Python, tal como `int` ou outro número, `str` ou `tuple`. 
Nesses casos, se queremos alterar o valor do conteúdo, é necessário atuar no `__new__` antes de chamar o `__new__` original. Depois disso, o valor já está configurado e não pode ser alterado.

Por exemplo, uma sub-classe de string que converta todo o conteúdo pra maiúsculas já na criação, poderia ser:

```py
class StrUpper(str):
    def __new__(cls, value):
         value = value.upper()
         return super().__new__(cls, value)
```

Note uma outra característica quando se implementa o `__new__`: na hora de chamar o método `__new__` da superclasse, com `super()`,  é necessário colocar o parâmetro `cls` explícitamente nos argumentos. Para métodos e métodos de classe normais, o `super()` já faz essa parte. O `__new__` é um método especial, por conta de como a linguagem funciona - apesar de se parecer com um método de classe, internamente ele é um método estático, e o `cls` sempre é adicionado explicitamente, e não pela linguagem.

Em outras palavras: usamos o `__new__` apenas para interceptar e alterar parâmetros em classes que consomem esses parâmetros já na criação. Além dos tipos imutáveis, é comum escrever o  `__new__` quando se cria uma metaclasse - que vai alterar algum comportamento na criação de classes em si. Fora esses casos, mesmo herdando de tipos nativos como `dict` e `list`, o basta usar o `__init__` mesmo.