# Alguns códigos em Python apresentam o "__class__" durante a criação de determinadas classes. Para que serve?

Tags: python, classes

Percebi que em determinados códigos em Python utiliza-se um `__class__`. Para que serve o mesmo?

Exemplo:

```py
class abstract1 (object):
  def __init__(self):
    if self.__class__ == abstract1: 
      raise NotImplementedError("Interfaces can't be instantiated")
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de onde viu isso?

Comment: Tiago, `__class__` e `__init__` são coisas completamente diferentes e confesso que nunca vi ninguém manipular `__class__` de uma classe. Você poderia [edit] sua pergunta e explicar melhor o que você viu?

Comment: Algumas perguntas que podem te ajudar: [Qual é a diferença entre `__init__` e `__new__`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177882/5878) [Quando devo usar `__init__` em funções dentro de classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109013/5878)

Comment: Aproveitando que editou, vamos tentar deixar mais claro. O `__class__` que cita é de qual linguagem? No título você diz "algumas linguagens" e no corpo da pergunta apresenta um exemplo em Python. A dúvida é sobre o Python apenas? Podemos assumir agora que você sabe o que é o método `__init__`?

Answer (score 3):

Todos os objetos no Python possuem alguns campos especiais que são somente leitura e armazenam informações sobre o mesmo que são utilizadas pela linguagem e podem ser utilizadas pelo desenvolvedor.

O campo [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) é um deles e armazena uma referência à classe daquele objeto. Isto é, quando você possui uma instância de uma classe você consegue acessar qual é a classe que foi instanciada.

Um exemplo simples:

```py
class Foo:
    ...

obj = Foo()

print(obj.__class__ is Foo)  # True
```

> Sobre o comportamento do `is`, leia [Em Python, quais as consequências em usar 'is' no lugar de '=='](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38104/5878)

Uma curiosidade é que a própria classe por si só é uma instância e possui uma classe:

```py
print(Foo.__class__)  # <class 'type'>
```

Agora o seu caso:

```py
class abstract1 (object):
  def __init__(self):
    if self.__class__ == abstract1: 
      raise NotImplementedError("Interfaces can't be instantiated")
```

Você definiu uma classe com nome `abstract1`; ela herda da classe `object` (isso era necessário no Python 2, mas no Python 3 não); possui um método inicializador `__init__` que será chamado quando for criada uma instância dessa classe. Como o objetivo seria abstrair o conceito de classe abstrata, que não pode ser instanciada, dentro do método inicializador é verificado se a classe utilizada na instância, `self.__class__`, é a própria classe `abstract1`, que não pode ser instanciada. Se for, levanta uma exceção `NotImplementedError`.

Assim, quando você tenta criar uma instância dessa classe, `obj = abstract1()`, você terá uma saída parecida com:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    obj = abstract1()
  File "main.py", line 4, in __init__
    raise NotImplementedError("Interfaces can't be instantiated")
NotImplementedError: Interfaces can't be instantiated
```

Porém se você herdar a classe você conseguirá instanciar normalmente:

```py
class Filha(abstract1):
    ...

obj = Filha()
```

Pois assim `self.__class__` será `Filha` e não mais `abstract1`.

Para mais informações, o Python possui um módulo nativo para trabalhar com classes abstratas, [*Abstract Base Classes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).