# Necessidade de usar @classmethod no __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem, objetos, metaclass

Estava lendo sobre [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) na documentação do Python e após [pesquisar aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+__new__+%5Bpython%5D) vi alguns exemplos de implementação e notei que a assinatura do método é:

```
def __new__(cls, *args **kwargs):
```

Aí me surgiram as dúvidas vendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177946/6333):

- Porque `cls` e não `self`?
- Não teria que ser utilizado o decorador [@classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)?
- Se isso for uma exceção, não quebraria regras do Zen of Python, como

  > Explicit is better than implicit.

  e

  > Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

  ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os métodos especiais, com nomes entre dois `__` como `__new__` e `__init__` são especiais por uma razão: eles são parte da especificação da linguagem - então
as regras pra esses métodos no mínimo valem tanto quanto a "regra" que diz que um método de classe tem que ser um "@classmethod".

Eu disse "no mínimo", mas de fato especificação da linguagem tem prerrogativa pra dizer quais métodos especiais serão classmethods, ou qualquer outro comportamento, sem precisar de um decorador.

O documento com essas especificações e que descreve, pelo menos de forma resumida, todos os métodos especiais da linguagem  é o [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) e sempre vale a pena dar uma lida nele.(Alguns dos métodos mágicos são usados em protocolos implementados na biblioteca padrão, mas não são parte da linguagem, então podem não estar nesse documento de Data Model. É o caso dos métodos especiais usados pelo `pickle`). Métodos que são classmethod por padrão são `__init_subclass__` e `__class_getattr__`, por exemplo.

VOltando ao `__new__`: ele na verdade não é nem sequer um classmethod também - por uma questão de implementação ele é um método estático (@staticmethod) - e é tão especial que quando a linguagem vai chamar o `__new__` ela inclui o attributo `cls` nos argumentos por um mecanismo diferente do que é usado quando o `cls` é incluido automaticamente para chamar um classmethod. Eu não sei as razões reais para isso - mas pode ser que seja só uma questão de herança - antes de existir a chamada  `super()` do Python, o jeito de chamar um método numa superclasse era colocar uma referência explícita da superclasse, com o nome do método. Só que ao fazer isso quando você estivesse modificando o `__new__` e fosse chamar, de dentro da sua implementção `object.__new__`, se `__new__` fosse um classmethod padrão iria receber `object` como argumento para "cls" - quando na verdade tem que receber a classe atual (a classe ou subclasse para a qual você está implementando o novo `__new__`).

Já volto a essa questão do staticmethod - primeiro, chamo a atenção para uma coisa: você cita o "zen of Python" - mas embora ele esteja na linguagem, e liste princípios gerais, e tenha sido tomado muito a sério por mais de uma geração de Pythonistas (inclusive por mim), ele é mais uma obra "artística" com linhas gerais do que regras. Mas mesmo que fossem - você cita: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules." dá pra dizer 3 coisas:

- o que o verso seguinte é justamente "Although practicality beats purity."
- e se levar em conta que deve haver uma "forma óbvia de fazer as coisas" ("There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.") , é claro que o método que vai *criar* uma instância quando ela não existe, não pode ser um método de instância - tem que ser um método de classe
- e mais importante que tudo: as regras **não** são quebradas nesse caso. É isso que vamos ver no restante do texto.

## As regras não são quebradas

Bom, como já descrito acima, como as regras são dadas pela especificação da linguagem, então a regra é "o método especial com o nome `__new__`" é um método estático que vai ser chamado com a classe como primeiro argumento" é a regra.  Ela não é quebrada.

Mas a coisa vai além disso, e aí que entra um ponto em que mesmo sem saber da definição do `__new__` no datamodel, você tinha uma interpretação errada do que é a "regra para classmethod". O fato é que não é o decorador "classmethod" que faz de um método um classmethod.  Um classmethod é um método que vai atuar levando em conta a classe e não instâncias da classe - e o Python tem mecanismos convenientes para injetar automaticamente a classe como argumento em uma chamada. O decorador "classmethod" é um das formas de habilitar esse mecanismo.

Mas, por exemplo, em Python 3, se você escrever um método sem nenhuma marcação especial, e chama-lo a partir da classe, a linguagem não vai injetar nenhum argumento para o primeiro parâmetro - você pode passar explicitamente a classe no primeiro parâmetro, e usa-lo exatamente como se fosse um método criado com `@classmethod`:

```py
class A:
    def metodo_de_Classe(cls):
         print(cls)

A.metodo_de_classe(A)
```

Só quando chamado a partir de uma instância o Python (Python3), vai injetar a instância como primeiro argumento.

O que o classmethod faz é criar um objeto que é um wrapper para a função decorada que faz com que quando ela seja recuperada, seja como atributo da classe, ou atributo da instância, o `cls` seja injetado - isso é bem fácil de fazer, e dá pra criar uma classe que funcione igualzinho ao classmethod com pouquíssimas linhas de Python:

```py
class MyClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.method(owner, *args, **kwargs)
```

Pronto - esse "MyClassMethod" pode ser usado em qualquer lugar que você usaria o "classmethod" built-in da linguagem. O que eu quero deixar claro com isso é: o decorador "@classmethod" não é parte da sintaxe nem da especificação da linguagem em si, ele é parte dos "built-in callables" - que estão sempre disponiveis sem nenhuma importação, mas que não são uma parte vital da linguagem. (Por favor, não leve isso a ferro e fogo - não pretendo cair na discussão se os builtins,e   mesmo a biblioteca padrão, são parte da "especificação da linguagem" ou não - vai depender mais do contexto do que de termos absolutos)

O mecanismo que faz isso funcionar - o que vai chamar o método `__get__` no trecho de código acima é o protocolo de descritores (descriptor protocol), esse sim, faz parte da especificação da linguagem (e seu papel está descrito no Data Model, que mencionei acima).

Mas mais ainda, há outros mecanismos que podem fazer um método funcionar como um método de classe sem usar o classmethod, nem explicitamente usando algo que implemente o protocolo de descritores: qualquer "método de instância" na metaclasse de uma classe vai ser um método de classe para ela. 
E isso vai funcionar naturalmente sem nenhum outro código ser necessário, pelo mecanismod e busca de atributos normal - que, ao não achar um atributo na instância, vai procura-lo na classe.

ENtão se eu quiser uma metaclasse que não mude nenhum outro comportamento da classe, mas insira métodos de classe "automaticamente" é só fazer:

```py
class AutoClassMethod(type):

    def register(cls):
        print(f"Called with {cls}")

class A(metaclass=AutoClassMethod):
    pass

A.register()
```

E na verdade, é mais esse tipo de coisa - o fato de que um método de instância  na classe de uma classe (a metaclasse) automaticamente seja um método de classe é que faz quem entende be a linguagem dizer que ela respeita "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules" - ele só funciona assim por conta da forma natural como acesso a atributos funciona - (isso é: não há uma referência explícita a isso na documentação - só funciona por que é assim que métodos funcionam:  se você chama um método em uma instância, ele é chamado com a instância como primeiro argumento - e classes são instâncias de suas metaclasses).

Uma nota interessante sobre métodos definidos assim: de novo, por conta das regras existentes (e que não são quebradas, afinal "Special cases aren't special enough to..."), um método na metaclasse vai funcionar como método de classe, mas não vai ser visível ou chamável a partir de *instâncias* daquela classe.

Ou seja, continuando o exmplo acima, se eu fizer:

```
a = A()
a.register()
```

vai ocorrer um "AttributeError". Alguns módulos de Python tiram proveito disso para implementar APIs para classes que não interfere nas instâncias - por exemplo, se você herdar sua classe de `abc.ABC` da biblioteca padrão, sua classe vai ter um método `register`, mas as instâncias dela não terão esse `register`.

**TL;DR:** com tudo o que foi dito, e relendo a sua questão, **sim**, acho que dá pra dizer que o `__new__` ser um classmethod **viola** a parte que diz "special cases are not special enough to break the rules" - por que causa uma surpresa, tanto é que surpreendeu você. Espero, no entanto, ter ficado claro no contexto que é o "zen of Python" que é algo que não é tão "ferro e fogo" assim - e ele mesmo tem provisões para isso ao dizer que "praticality beats purity".

Comment: jsbueno, a resposta está excelente! Além de responder as perguntas que eu tinha e de explicar coisas que eu entendia mas não explicitei na pergunta, você ainda me explicou perguntas que eu nem havia pensado ainda.